# Package a JAR Within Maven Plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven plugin which has a dependency which needs to be packaged within it (for reasons). So I build my dependency, output a JAR, and install it into the target plugin project. By installing I include the hash and other Maven files to ensure it's being pulled in correctly. Like so:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>additional-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <packaging>${project.packaging}</packaging>
                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</file>
                <localRepositoryPath>${project.basedir}/../target-maven-plugin/src/main/resources/libs/repo</localRepositoryPath>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As you can see, it is being placed into the resource directory of the target project. I do not want to copy the code as this is a fork of another internally maintained project and don't want to have to move/update all the code and tests - I've simply renamed the path.

Within the target project I create a repo and then use it by using the local repo:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>TargetMavenPluginInternalRepo</id>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/libs/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then I include that as a dependency:

```xml
<!-- This is a JAR which is located in the libs/ directory. -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.needed</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
    <version>${dependency.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The project builds and installs as expected. The plugin is installed into the target maven plugin local repo and builds/runs corrects by itself.

However, if I try to run the plugin via a downstream project, it fails because the downstream project which is using the target Maven plugin cannot locate that dependency. It kind of makes sense. I can see Maven trying to resolve the dependency:

```sh
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/company/needed/1.1/dependency-1.1.jar
Downloading from TargetMavenPluginInternalRepo: file:${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/libs/repo/com/company/needed/dependency/1.1/dependency-1.1.jar
```

So I went ahead and am trying some things such as copying the dependency into the target jar and then trying to add it to the classpath:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <groupId>com.company.needed</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency</artifactId>
                <version>${dependency.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This seems like a long way to accomplish this. My colleagues suggested I just copy the code over but I like having it outside so it's easier to maintain and so I can pull in updates easier.

Thoughts? Is this even possible? I don't want to externally publish this internally maintained dependency.

Comment: Maybe you can use the assembly plugin or the shade plugin for this ... by the way, I do not understand why you need this complicated stuff to install and manage the dependency inside the project. Don't you have a company Nexus/Artifactory?

Comment: It's not proprietary code but a fork that's been heavily modified of a public project (org.reflections actually). The target Maven plugin is public. I could just copy and paste the results of the build pipe into the target Maven plugin and call it a day.

Comment: You write that you build your dependency ... why not deploy it to your Nexus, then you can use it inside your plugin (shading or assembly is another issue, of course)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. However, how will the public grab that dependency? My thought was to include it within the target Maven plugin.

Comment: These are two different issues: (1) Where do you load the dependency from? (2) How do you include it into the plugin? For (1) I advice you to use Nexus/Artifactory.